# How to find previous tag in xml using XSL?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML file as below.

```
<p>Sample Content 1</p>
<p>Sample Content 2</p>
<sec level="1">Sample Content 3</sec>
<p>Sample Content 4</p>
<p>Sample Content 5</p>
```

XSL Transformation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="p">
 <xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="preceding-sibling::p">
   <p class="indent"><xsl:apply-templates /></p>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
   <p class="noindent"><xsl:apply-templates /></p>
  </xsl:otherwise>
 </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I need the output for below format.

```
<p class="noindent">Sample Content 1</p>
<p class="indent">Sample Content 2</p>
<h1>Sample Content 3</h1>
<p class="noindent">Sample Content 4</p>
<p class="indent">Sample Content 5</p>
```

Please tell the idea for above concept. So I have to find out the previous tag format..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why do you need to find previous tag? add your xsl experiment in question.

Comment: xslt version you use ?

Comment: you got an answer. If you use saxon, you can have a counter validate conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the conditions into match patterns and change the condition to `preceding-sibling::*[1][self::p]`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="p">
        <p class="noindent">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </p>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="p[preceding-sibling::*[1][self::p]]">
        <p class="indent">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </p>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your only error is thinking that `preceding-sibling::p` means "the immediately preceding sibling is a `p`", when in fact it means "there is at least one `p` among the preceding siblings".  In your tests replace `preceding-sibling::p` with `preceding-sibling::*[1]/self::p`.

The structural change suggested by Martin Honnen (use multiple templates instead of one) is usually a good idea but unrelated to the failure of your code to give you what you expected.